# elements Getting Random in for Each and fetching data from firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
    
    fireDetail.forEach((element) async {
      await checkEach(element);
     
    });
  }

  checkEach(element) async {
    print(element.path);
    await Firestore.instance
        .document('${element.path}/likedBy/$currentUser')
        .get()
        .then((value) => print(element.path));   
  }
```

/flutter ( 6906): fire/c0829bb0-2dce-11eb-be17-6debf3d459db

I/flutter ( 6906): fire/b9a45680-2dce-11eb-b289-d9b50dcbb605

I/flutter ( 6906): fire/89aa14b0-2dce-11eb-b507-672e33a10129

I/flutter ( 6906): fire/6cebfcd0-2dce-11eb-8a61-9909929ac404


//below is the order from .then 
 
I/flutter ( 6906): fire/89aa14b0-2dce-11eb-b507-672e33a10129
I/flutter ( 6906): fire/c0829bb0-2dce-11eb-be17-6debf3d459db
I/flutter ( 6906): fire/6cebfcd0-2dce-11eb-8a61-9909929ac404
I/flutter ( 6906): fire/b9a45680-2dce-11eb-b289-d9b50dcbb605

Why is the order of forEach and .then changed? 
It could be seen the elements sent by for each is different from the elements printed inside .then(value).. due to which further codes get messed up. How can this problem be resolved?

Comment: Hey, I tried your solution but it still printed in random order. So in place of using for each function, I used For loop. I know there isn't much difference, but it worked in my case.

Comment: You migth want to post that as an answer in that case, so that others can easily find what worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

The calls to Firestore happen asynchronously. While your `await Firestore.instance` makes `checkEach` wait, it doesn't synchronize the multiple calls to `checkEach` since you're not returning anything.

The easiest way to synchronize across the calls is to `await` on the calls to `forEach`, and thus have that return the `Future` from Firestore:

```
fireDetail.forEach((element) async {
  await checkEach(element);     
});

checkEach(element) async {
  return Firestore.instance
    .document('${element.path}/likedBy/$currentUser')
    .get()
    .then((value) => print(element.path));   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering it too late, But this how I tackled this issue

```
checkIsLiked(List fireDetail) async {
 
    for (var i in fireDetail) {
      await checkEach(i);
    }
     }

  checkEach(element) async {
    print(element.path);
    await Firestore.instance
        .document('${element.path}/likedBy/$currentUser')
        .get()
        .then((value) => print(element.path));   
  }
```

I replaced forEach with typical for loop.